# Unable to access spring-docs-open-ui swagger documentation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc, springdoc-openui

I am a spring newbie trying to configure swagger documentation for my spring boot application. I configured my application based on the documentation provided [here](https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/)

I am able to access the documentation page locally from this URL

> http://localhost:8080/doc.html

However, when I deploy my application on Docker I keep getting a 404 status.

> https://www.mywebsite.com/context_path/doc.html

My application.properties file looks like this -

```
springdoc.api-docs.path=/doc
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/doc.html
```

I have also added a HomeController which redirects to the documentation page

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public void redirect(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/doc.html");
    }

}
```

FYI, I am using Amazon Cognito. I have read and tried several examples that I found online but I cannot make this work. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are using only `@Controller` annotation; 
If you are using REST APIs, you should use `@RestController`.
If you need to use `@Controller`, you should add `@ResponseBody`

If you don't want change your @Controller, you add:

```
static {
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addRestControllers(HelloController.class);
}
```

More information are available on the documentation of F.A.Q:

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#my-rest-controller-using-controller-annotation-is-ignored